# Is there an open source stereoscopic interface for QGIS, like PurVIEW or DAT/EM, or stereo Analyst?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, interface

I have a lot of imagery processing that I do at the local college, and most of the imagery is stereo imagery.  Is there an open source piece of software that could be used to view the imagery and perhaps integrate it with open source GIS software, like QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know only One Efoto http://www.efoto.eng.uerj.br/about-e-foto?lang=en